# Proving $F(x)$ is a CDF using the PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I have to prove $F(x)$ is a CDF. I wanted to show that by using the PDF, but I encounter a problem.

The original CDF is

$$F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text { si } & x<0 \\
\frac{x^{2}}{3} & \text { si } & 0 \leqslant x<1 \\
\frac{1}{3} & \text { si } & 1 \leqslant x<2 \\
\frac{1}{6} x+\frac{1}{3} & \text { si } & 2 \leqslant x<4 \\
1 & \text { si } & 4\leqslant x .
\end{array}\right.$$

I am thinking there might me a typo since integrating the PDF yields $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)\neq 1$.

But if

$$F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text { si } & x<0 \\
\frac{x^{2}}{3} & \text { si } & 0 \leqslant x<1 \\
\frac{x}{3} & \text { si } & 1 \leqslant x<2 \\
\frac{1}{6} x+\frac{1}{3} & \text { si } & 2 \leqslant x<4 \\
1 & \text { si } & 4\leqslant x ,
\end{array}\right.$$

Then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)= 1$.

So I'm thinking, should I use another method for proving $F(x)$ is A CDF or is there indeed a typo and I can use the PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have show in that their is a massive step in $F(x)$ at $x=2$.

That $F(2)-\lim\limits_{y\uparrow 2}F(2)=1/3$.  The function is not *left* continuous.

This does not mean that it is not a CDF, only that their is not a pdf for this random variable. (The random variable is not a continuous random variable.)  However, that is not an issue; a CDF may have a *left* discontinuity.

A random variable does *not need* to have a pdf in order to have a CDF.

---

To show that a function is a CDF, you need to ensure that it

- Limits to $0$ as $x$ approaches $-\infty$.  $\quad\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} F(x)=0$ .
- Limits to $1$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$.  $\quad\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F(x)=1$.
- Is an nondecreasing function.  $\quad\forall x~\forall y~(x<y\to F(x)\leqslant F(y))$.
- Is everywhere *right* continuous.  $\quad\forall x~\lim\limits_{y\downarrow x}F(y)=F(x)$.